# Difference between '2>&1' and '&>filename'

Tags: linux, shell

I'm an beginner in Linux, I have a question about redirecting STDOUT and STDERR.

1. Create a `file1` to add some strings

   ```
   echo hello > file1
   ```

   After this, when I do something like this

   ```
   cat file1 file2
   ```

   It will give an error like this

   ```
   hello
   cat: file2: No such file or directory
   ```
2. I want to redirect the STDOUT and STDERR, so

   ```
   cat file1 file2 > file3 2>&1 | cat
   hello
   cat: file2: No such file or directory
   ```
3. I know that `|` can use last command's output as its input, right?
   So the first `cat`'s output is:

   ```
   hello
   cat: file2: No such file or directory
   ```
4. Now, I find another method to redirect output, like:

   ```
   cat file1 file2 &> file3
   cat file3
   hello
   cat: file2: No such file or directory
   ```
5. It can do the same thing, but when I add `|cat` , the result is

   ```
   cat file1 file2 &> file3 | cat
   hello
   ```

   Where is the STDERR? It means only `hello` is the output of the first `cat`?

What the difference between `2>&1` and `&>file`?

Comment: Are you sure that `cat file1 file2 &> file3 | cat` produces output?  It should not.

Comment: both are semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> cat file1 file2
> ```
>
> It will give an error like this
>
> ```
> hello cat: file2: No such file or directory
> ```

The error is simply telling you **`file2` does not exist**. You create `file1` with your redirection:

```
echo hello > file1
```

Now `file1` exists. When you do `cat file1 file2`, `cat` attempts to output the contents of `file1` & `file2` to `stdout`, but `file2` doesn't exist (it tells you). To make `file2`, you can do `cat file1 > file2` to redirect the output of `cat file1` to `file2`, or you can simply `cp file1 file2`. Then `file2` will exist.

> I want to redirect the STDOUT and STDERR, so
>
> ```
> cat file1 file2 > file3 2>&1 | cat
> hello
> cat: file2: No such file or directory
> ```

Again, `file2` still doesn't exist. `cat` short for `concatenate` simply output the contents of the files given as input to `stdout` unless redirected. `file1` contains `hello` so it is output along with the error. `hello` is redirected to `file3`, ...and..., since you have redirected `stderr` to `stdout` (e.g. `2>&1`), the error message also ends up in `file3`

The `|` (pipe) command in Linux shell just takes the `stdout` from the command on the left and redirects it to the `stdin` of the command after the pipe. Since you already redirected the `stdout` and `stderr` from `cat file1 file2` into `file3`, nothing is sent to the `cat` following the pipe. The output you posted appears to have come from:

```
cat file3
```

In a Linux shell, `stdin, stdout and stderr` are simply special files that represent file descriptors `0, 1 & 2`, respectively. The actual files in the filesystem are `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout`, and `/dev/stderr`. If you check with the `ls -l` command, you will see the relation between the file and file descriptors:

```
$ ls -l /dev/std*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr  2 17:47 /dev/stderr -> fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr  2 17:47 /dev/stdin -> fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr  2 17:47 /dev/stdout -> fd/1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The output `hello` appears on standard output.  The error message appears on standard error.  Henceforth, those will be stdout and stderr.
2. You claim that `cat file1 file2 > file3 2>&1 | cat` produces some output on the terminal.  It doesn't with any standard shell.  When I run it, it produces no visible output, but `file3` contains the line from `file1` and the error message.  Since there's no input for it to read, the second `cat` command exits without producing any output.

   The `> file3` redirection sends stdout to `file3`.  The `2>&1` sends stderr to the same place that stdtout is going.  File descriptor 0 is standard input (stdin), 1 is stdout, and 2 is stderr.
3. There is no output sent to the pipe; it is all sent to the file (but the pipe is created first, then stdout is redirected to the file).
4. These commands demonstrate that all the output (stdout and stderr) was written to `file3`.
5. You claim that `cat file1 file2 &> file3 | cat` produces some output on the terminal.  It doesn't with Bash; there is no output because both stdout and stderr go to `file3`.
6. The difference between `&> file3` and `> file3 2>&1` is portability (the `&>` notation is less portable) and number of characters; functionally, they're equivalent.